# Difference between building Tkinter app inside and outside function

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

i was working on building an GUI application with tkinter then i came across with this frustration.

When i try to created a simple program that change picture when i clicked a button ,i first declared every tkinter widget inside the function called buildGUI() then i ran the code and that simple program couldn't change a picture .

But when i put all the code from buildGUI() outside of it , program can run just fine.

Why is this happening?

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk,Image 

## GUI 
frame = tkinter.Tk()
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(frame)
detect_frame= ttk.Frame(tab_control)
label1 = ttk.Label()
box1 = ttk.Label()
btn1 = ttk.Button()
##
example = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("gui_data/goose.png"))

def changeIMG():
    print("Changing image ")
    global example
    example = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("gui_data/overwork.jpg").resize((320,320)))
    box1.configure(image=example)
def buildGUI():
    global example
    icon = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("gui_data/icon.jpg"))

    frame.title('IOT-Project_TEST')
    frame.geometry("800x600")
    frame.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    frame.iconphoto(False,icon)

    tab_control.add(detect_frame,text='Detect Zone')
    tab_control.pack(expand=1,fill="both")

    button_style = ttk.Style().configure("def.TButton",font=("Courier",16))
    label1 = ttk.Label(detect_frame,text="Detect Zone")
    box1 = ttk.Label(detect_frame,image=example,borderwidth=5,relief='solid')
    btn1 = ttk.Button(detect_frame,text="Open Camera",command=changeIMG,style="def.TButton")

    label1.pack()
    box1.pack(pady="10")
    btn1.pack(pady=10,ipadx="10",ipady="10")

frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: It’s because the default scope of variables is to be local within functions.

Comment: @quamrana so if i want my buildGUI() to work , i have to tell variable that it from global variable like global example?

Comment: You could return box1 from buildGUI()

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of `local` scope of `box1` which you declared inside `buildGUI()` method. This variable is not available outside the function. Thus, when you try to do this:
`box1.configure(image=example)`, it doesn't work.

You can do two things:

1. Create the variables `global` of whose values you want to change outside the function.
2. Along with function call, you can send the object you want to make changes to.
   Example -

```py
btn1.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e:changeIMG(box1))    #Inside buidGUI
```

You can read more about scope [here](https://pythonbasics.org/scope/)